# Host key verification failed when running a system service

Tags: ssh, services, systemctl

I intend to run a python script as a service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Description
Wants=network-online.target
After=multi-user.target network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/path/to/python /path/to/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script connects to a remote computer. When I run the script with `/path/to/python /path/to/script.py` in the shell, it works fine. There are no errors. But when the service is running, I do not see the intended results.

On checking the status, I see the following repeating:

```
Jul 2 00:00:41 user systemd[1]: Description
Jul 2 00:00:42 user python[12121212]: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Jul 2 00:00:42 user python[12121212]: Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH connections are (often) based on a concept of "trust on first use", which is why (interactively) you get a prompt asking you if you trust the fingerprint of the remote host('s key) when you first connect.

This obviously does not work for a non-interactive service. Try `sudo`ing to the user the service is running as (root, from your service file?) and connecting to the remote server. Once you have trusted the key, this is saved in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and your service should run.

(If your service uses `paramiko`, it hopefully calls `load_system_host_keys()` to load this file.)